# Bottom fixed div keeps jumping when scrolling on iPhone

Tags: iphone

I am working on a responsive design where I have a div container that should be fixed at the bottom of the viewport. The problem is that the div keeps moving when I scroll up/down the page and it takes a little while until its back in its fixed position.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this jumping around? What else can I do than position: fixed and bottom: 0?

Thanks!! :)

Comment: What version of iOS are you testing in?

Comment: iOS5. I read around and it says that iOS5 supports fixed divs but for some reason this does not apply in my case

Comment: Ok, finally found a solution! I had the fixed div included within the scrollable element. Putting the div outside the other div fixed the issue. Stupid me! :)

Comment: Glad you figured it out! Btw, it's helpful to post a snippet of code along with applicable CSS/JS in your question. That way, you have another set of eyes helping you catch those things. Have a good one!

Comment: Thanks for the info. Also, you must specify an x-axis position for the element, or else it'll jump around (right:0 or left:0 (or whatever fits with your design). cheers!

Answer (score 6):

Using `position: sticky;` instead of `position: fixed;` solved jumping problem on iOS for me.

Answer (score 3):

did you try:

`-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;`

or maybe

`-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch`

Hope this helps you !

Comment: @SagiveSEO am curious as to which tag in specific worked for you. We are running into the same problem.

Comment: It actually works for me by removing the 
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch

Comment: Should one use these on the container or on the fixed object?

Comment: I tried all of these and they didn't work

Answer (score 2):

There is a great article here. In my case I had the fixed element *inside* of the scrolling div. Once I placed it outside, no more jitters.

https://remysharp.com/2012/05/24/issues-with-position-fixed-scrolling-on-ios

Answer (score 2):

For my current project, I had a `<nav>` element with a fixed position nested inside a `<header>` element with its own fixed position (semantically it could make sense to nest the nav the header for the DOM tree, but visually we wanted them to appear in separate places within the UI). Moving the nav out of the header, making it an immediate child of the `<body>` element, solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a CSS block like this which was causing the issue.

```
html,
body {
  overflow-x: clip;
  ...other styles
}
```

After the scrollable container tips above didn't work, I thought maybe the double overflow was the issue. I'm not sure why, but this fixed it for me:

```
html,
body {
  ...other styles
}

html {
  overflow-x: clip;
}
```